# What is this type of graph called and how can it be plotted in R

Tags: r, graph, visualization

[image: Transference among nodes]

A graph to indicate the percentage of elements from one node that are transferred to another node in two different stages. In principle, the number of nodes in one stage need not be equal to the number of nodes in the next stage. I would like to know the name of this type of graph and if it is possible to create it in R.

Comment: A sankey diagram. See e.g. https://r-charts.com/flow/sankey-diagram-ggplot2/ or https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/ for plotting options in R

Comment: Another name for this specific type of Sankey diagram is "alluvial diagram". You can find several R implementations, e.g. **alluvial** https://github.com/mbojan/alluvial **ggalluvial** http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/ **easyalluvial** https://www.datisticsblog.com/2018/10/intro_easyalluvial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sankey diagram:

https://r-graph-gallery.com/sankey-diagram.html

You could find more info how to do it here:

https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/